Can onion consumption cause Heinz bodies in humans?
It was well attested that eating onions can cause the presence of Heinz bodies in the blood of cats, dogs, and other animals, due to the toxic effect of, apparently, thiosulfate, which denatures hemoglobin. Google scholar finds numerous articles corroborating this, but I'm having trouble finding relevant information for humans. Can eating raw onions cause the presence of Heinz bodies in humans at some dose?

May or may not be helpful: Humans have been eating onions, garlic, leeks, etc. (which are variably toxic in some animals) for centuries; cats, dogs and water buffalo (etc.) have not. OTOH, lots of people have onion intolerance. What is the basis for human onion/garlic intolerance? Searching for that question is more likely to get you helpful results than taking a stab in the dark with what's toxic for only some animals. (Not my down vote.)

Thanks @anongoodnurse. I have removed the reference to onion intolerance to keep the question more focused. I honestly can't imagine why anyone would downvote a perfectly valid question.

Humans are capable of breaking down a great number of toxins other animals have trouble with, it is an adaptation to eating cooked food. perhaps onion is one of them.
